# Git - remove remote branch with a space in the branch name

Tags: git

I'm not exactly sure how this happened, but we have a branch on our remote repository that has a space in it's name:

```
remotes/origin/Dev 3
```

I'm trying to remove this branch using the following command, but it wont work, I think because of the spaces:

```
git push origin :Dev 3
```

I've also tried different variants, such as:

```
git push origin :Dev\ 3
git push origin :Dev3
git push origin :'Dev 3'
git push origin ':Dev 3'
```

None of these work, I get the following error:

```
error: unable to delete 'Release': remote ref does not exist
error: src refspec 3 does not match any.
```

Any ideas on how I could remove this remote branch please?

Comment: Have you tried `git push origin --delete Dev 3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it!

So I was using Netbeans and GitK to view the branches and through those tools, the branch name is "Dev 3". But I tried a listing using 'git branch -a' and it turns out, the branch name is "Dev_3"!

So I did a git push origin :Dev_3 and that got rid of it. No idea why the other tools are not showing the underscore.

Thanks!